# S3: renaming objects fails with access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to 'rename' a bunch of prefixed objects in s3 but it keeps giving me `<Access Denied>`. I can get the object and I can put objects. I have no reason to believe I couldn't just download every object one by one and re-`put_object` with the new name but I'd prefer not to do that if possible.

`aws s3 cp s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/1050/currency s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/1050/currency2` -> `copy failed: s3://XXXXXXXXXXXX/1050/currency to s3://XXXXXXXXXXX/1050/currency2 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied`

same happens when I use the `mv` command.

is there something about copying in the same bucket, or even in the same prefix that isn't allowed? here's the policy for the role i'm using:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:Describe*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "logs:*",
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can look at **AWS CloudTrail** to identify the API calls that are failing, which should suggest the permissions required.

Comment: AWS S3 Object Rename is a copy followed by delete. You need the deleteObject* permissions. You also might need the additional GetObject* and PutObject* permissions (versions, tagging, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the files you are trying to copy may have tags applied. Try adding the two additional permissions below:

`s3:GetObjectTagging`

`s3:PutObjectTagging`

Comment: I kind of think this is the answer, i ended up just manually adjusting the data I needed to in s3, so didn't actually resolve the issue. selecting this to highlight this for other users. these were permissions I didn't realize I needed, but considering all our s3 objects are tagged, this is probably the correct answer

Comment: I added these permissions and it solved my problem. Thanks! 
However, I had a policy that allows me to do everything on any resource and yet I couldn't rename S3 objects without adding a policy with these actions. Anyone knows why?